# How much overhead does prototype scope cause?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My understanding is that a prototype-scoped Java bean class is instantiated every time it is requested, as opposed to singleton-scoped Java beans which are instantiated once when the application starts up.

My question is: how much overhead does using the prototype scope cause?

- Does the Spring framework make any attempt to recycle prototype-scoped objects to reduce the overhead caused by repeated instantiation?
- Is the overhead caused by prototype scoping enough to warrant efforts to make as many of my Java bean classes stateless so that I can apply singleton scope to them?

Comment: I can't answer your question but I never use Prototype scope because all my beans are stateless. What's the reason for using Prototype scope in your case?

Comment: same overhead as creating new object everytime,

Comment: Why prototype scope ? Why to take the overhead of cleaning up beans all by yourself ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli My beans are stateful (they contain instance variables), and they may be serving multiple requests simulatneously. I'm worried that there will be thread-safety issues if my beans are not scoped as prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

Using prototype scope is the same as if you were to instantiate using 'new' except that the new object will be managed by Spring.  Spring will be able to apply aspects, inject dependencies, etc..  There will also be the overhead of the proxy class created to wrap the object.

Spring will not attempt to reuse the instances.

If you do not want to create a new instance whenever you reference the bean then you should not be using a prototype.  Your solution will either require independent instances, maybe due to concurrency, or it will allow for a singleton.  It is unlikely that the memory used by the object will be the deciding factor for what scope you use.

Answer (score 1):

You should not think of overhead between the prototype and singleton scope, but only the way they are used. If they are stateless objects that will live throughout the life time of the application, the correct scope is singleton. Many beans exist in that scope, for example controllers, beans in a service or persistence layer. Most beans related to Spring Security framework are also stateless and live in singleton scope.

If you want to create a brand new bean for a specific processing and then discard it when it has been used, then it is a use case for the prototype scope. As I mainly used spring for Web application I seldom used prototype scoped beans, but used request scoped beans which have a close use case: they are created for a HTTP request processing. The only point of attention is that if you have to inject a prototype or request scoped bean in a singleton bean, you will have to use a proxy that allows to *connect* to the current prototype bean (may be in thread storage) and not a bean that would have been created when the singleton was.